# Grid of photos - multiple select/highlight? Toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a grid of photos. What I need is the user to be able to click on the photos of people they want to invite to an event. Upon first click I'd like it to alter the CSS/styling (for example add a border or change transparency) then on second click revert back to original style. So toggle I guess.

So that a user can click say three images and those three would have a green border showing they've been selected. Then if he'd like to deselect he simply click again and it reverts back to the original style.

How is this possible? CSS? Javascript? JQuery?

So far all I've got is the table of photos:

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted, just to let you know this SO isn't a free crowdsourcing site where you can simple pass an idea to people and they build it.

Comment: @chris, I'll be lenient as this is his first question. However EdzJohnson, please keep in mind what Chris say. I hope you have read FAQs and are clear about what and how to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTML

```
<div class="user">john</div>
<div class="user">doe</div>
<div class="user">larry</div>
<div class="user">sergey</div>​
```

### CSS

```
.user {border: 1px solid #ededed; cursor: pointer; width: 100px; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px}
.active {border: 1px solid #0066cc; background: #eeeeee;}​
```

### jQuery

```
$('.user').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qgGne/